# Condenser and electret microphone use

Tags: condenser-microphone

Can a condenser or electret microphone be used as a speaker if all necessary related components are included in the circuit?

Comment: Yes, if one of those related necessary components is an actual speaker.

Answer (score 2):

No.  While it probably is possible to cause the diaphragm to move with an applied signal, the resulting audio will be severely distorted and almost completely inaudible.  You would have better luck with a dynamic microphone, which is essentially the same construction as a speaker.  But again, a microphone element is designed for very small movements of the diaphragm, exactly the opposite of what you want in a speaker.

Answer (score 0):

Electret microphones have built-in preamplifier circuits which would prevent the electrical signal from getting to the transducer.  There is a type of earphone (the "crystal earphone") that does use a piezoelectric element to convert sound to electricity, but in addition to not having an amplifier, the mechanical and acoustical design is considerably different.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but be prepared for problems. They can be used as speaker (I did use them in such a way), but they include several major drawbacks when used as speakers. First you need microphone with only diaphragm as included electronic will prevent (usually FET impedance converter) such use. Other major drawback is very low acoustic signal even at maximum voltage before destruction. For addition hardware I used small SSR relay to switch between microphone and speaker mode as drive voltage (+-40V) would destroy used microphone amplifier.